# Gradle: exclude dependencies from inside an aar

Tags: android, gradle

I have imported an *aar* library to my project, included it in *libs* folder and added to gradle like following:

```
compile ('com.adclient.android.sdk:adclient-sdk-for-android-3.3.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

The thing is that the *aar* cointains some dependencies inside that are also compiled in my project, and I get duplication errors.
If I get the dependencies tree, the library looks empty:

```
+--- com.adclient.android.sdk:adclient-sdk-for-android-3.3.0:
```

Also, if I use *exclude* in the library compile statement, it has no effect. E.g:

```
compile ('com.adclient.android.sdk:adclient-sdk-for-android-3.3.0@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3',  module: 'okhttp'
    transitive = true
}
```

I can exclude duplicated dependencies within the other libraries, but I prefer to keep them in the new dependency addition.
So, is it possible to exclude dependencies inside the *aar*? What I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

This is the type of error I'm getting. It's a warning but our ProGuard stops because of that:

> Copying resources from program jar
>   [/Users/adalpari/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.9.0/1b6c10b5120995a7542c1a31b7828fb8593c8ba/okhttp-3.9.0.jar]
>   (filtered) Warning: Exception while processing task
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write
>   [/Users/adalpari/X/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/production/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar]
>   (Can't read
>   [/Users/adalpari/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.9.0/1b6c10b5120995a7542c1a31b7828fb8593c8ba/okhttp-3.9.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
>   (Duplicate zip entry [okhttp3/a.class ==
>   okhttp-3.9.0.jar:okhttp3/Address.class]))
>   :AndroidApp:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease
>   FAILED

Comment: Try : `configurations.all { exclude group: '*' }`